# How to run Python script in background in android?

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer, python-for-android

I want to run a specific Python file(for example, main.py) in android device even if my app is not running in the foreground using my android application made using Python, Kivy and Buildozer .

Comment: If `main.py` starts a Kivy `App`, then you must use another `Process` to run it (See [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/multiprocessing.html), [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/subprocess.html), and [concurent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor)). If `main.py` is not another `App`, just use [threads](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/threading.html).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['python main.py'])
```